# how do display the another set of menu-items by selecting particular menu from menu list?

Tags: android

In my application I am having 3 menu like options,setting and favorites. In that If I press 'favorites' means it should display another set of (new)menu and I want to hide the previous set of (old)menu. IS it possible with android? If anyone knows, help me please.

Comment: Could anyone help me for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is possible, but it's not the bast idea to do such things. Main reason - this behavior will be unexpected for user.

On selecting option menu item you should show alert dialog with possible choices.

Offtopic: According new [design guidelines](http://developer.android.com/design/index.html) Android will delete "menu button", and all actions will appear on [action bar](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/actionbar.html). May be this will be better for your purposes.